How to calculate $\mathbf{s}_k^{\rm T} \mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{s}_k$ within the L-BFGS approach?
I have recently found a paper dealing with a damped L-BFGS procedure. In that work, the authors used the following quantities in their expressions:
$b_k = \mathbf{s}^{\rm T}_k \mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{s}_k$
and
$h_k = \mathbf{y}^{\rm T}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{y}_k$,
where $\mathbf{s}_k = \mathbf{x}_{k+1} - \mathbf{x}_k$ is a step vector, $\mathbf{y}_k = \mathbf{g}_{k+1} - \mathbf{g}_k$ is a gradient change, as well as $\mathbf{B}_k$ and $\mathbf{H}_k$ are an approximate Hessian and its inverse, respectively. Nevertheless, they did not mention how parameters $b_k$ and $h_k$ could be calculated within the framework of the L-BFGS approach. Could you please help me how these parameters can be expressed via the L-BFGS history of size $m$? I guess that $h_k$ can exploit the recursive formula available for $-\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{g}_k$, but is there a similar one for $\mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{s}_k$, as well?

I think you are right that the implementation of $h_k$ is straightforward given how $H_k$ is stored. For the computation involving $B_k$, Section 7.2 of Nodecal & Wright has some discussion of similarly efficient implementations of $B_k$.

@whpowell96 Thanks for your book recommendation. Indeed, "Procedure 7.6 (Unrolling the BFGS formula)" seems to be a useful L-BFGS representation of the original BFGS expression.
